# Formatting data as a block in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

Below is my sample data. How can it be filter based on start time and end time using grok pattern. Any idea friends since the data came as a stream of blocks. Can you guys suggest and provid example. I need to know start time , end time, success or fail. if fail the message

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Name: My file name
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Begin Date: MM/DD/YYYY
Begin Time: HH:MM:SS

Activity
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS message
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS message
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Result
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
message Completed
End Date:   MM/DD/YYYY
End Time:   HH:MM:SS
Executed by: Name
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Name: My file name
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Begin Date: MM/DD/YYYY
Begin Time: HH:MM:SS

Activity
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS message
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS message
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Result
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
message Failed
ERROR:  message
ERROR:  message
 at stacktrace
 at stacktrace
Caused by: message
 at stacktrace
 at stacktrace
    
End Date:   MM/DD/YYYY
End Time:   HH:MM:SS
Executed by: Name
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Look into the `multiline` [codec plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html) for logstash. If you want more help here, post your pipeline config.

Comment: usually multiline can be used in beat when passing data to logstash where it pass as block. how to format after that in logstash to get the date time messages

Comment: If you want more help here, post your pipeline config. Also post your beats config (especially the multiline bit) and example of the message as Logstash sees it (probably by sending it to the `stdout` output)